# cfajaxproxy is sending invalid parameters?

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

For some reason that I don't understand, on my development machine can't call to function of a cfc component from a cfajaxproxy.

In my cfm document:

```
<cfajaxproxy cfc="#Application.CfcPath#.empleado" 
                jsclassname="ccEmpleado">
```

This works, and also I can instantiate an object to get all the functions of that cfc component:

```
var cfcEmpleado = new ccEmpleado();
```

But, when I try to call a function of that object:

```
var nb_Empleado = cfcEmpleado.RSEmpeladoNombreBIND(1,1);
```

Debug complains:
Error: The ID_EMPRESA parameter to the RSEmpeladoNombreBIND function is required but was not passed in.

I got this from Network tab on Chrome and figured out that something is generating an invalid parameter:

```
http://127.0.0.1/vpa/componentes/empleado.cfc?method=RSEmpeladoNombreBIND&_cf_ajaxproxytoken=[object%20Object]&returnFormat=json&_cf_nodebug=true&_cf_nocache=true&_cf_clientid=41C92098C98042112AE2B3AAF523F289&_cf_rc=0
```

As you can see, there's a parameter `[object%20Object]`, that is messing around my request, and that's why it fails. I don't why is happening this. Other people has tested this, and it works, but in mine doesn't.

I have Coldfusion 9, Apache, Windows 8. Is is some configuration issue on Coldfusion, or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if this is your error or not, but it might be.  This was a problem that we had for awhile.  You should consider using explicit names to avoid any confusion. Add the "js" in there.

```
<cfajaxproxy cfc="cfcEmpleado" jsclassname="proxyEmpleado">

var jsEmpleado = new proxyEmpleado();
```

I will try to find a link to an article about this very thing.